# Prove that $\alpha^n+\beta^n+\gamma^n \equiv 4^n+5^n+(-6)^n \pmod{17}$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ be the roots of $x^3-3x^2+1 = 0$. Prove that $$\alpha^n+\beta^n+\gamma^n \equiv 4^n+5^n+(-6)^n \pmod{17}$$ where $n$ is an integer.

It sort of makes sense why they are congruent since we can say $x^3-3x^2+1 \equiv (x-4)(x-5)(x+6) \pmod{17}$, but since $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ aren't integers, how do we prove this?

Comment: @Starfall My book says it follows from the fact that $x^3-3x^2+1 \equiv (x-4)(x-5)(x+6) \pmod{17}$. How?

Comment: Even though the individual roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are not integers, the sum of the powers of these roots are.

Comment: @user51819 Yes, but how do the roots modulo $17$ of the equation relate to the congruence?

Comment: They relate in the sense that both polynomials $x^3-3x^2+1=0$ and $(x-4)(x-5)(x+6) = 0$ have the same root power sums mod $17$. The power sums are integers even though the individual roots may not be (in the case of the first polynomial).

Comment: @user51819 How do you know they have the same root power sums modulo $17$? That is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Look up Newton's Identities https://brilliant.org/wiki/newtons-identities/#newtons-identities-for-a-cubic-polynomial

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ Both sides satisfy the associated recurrence $\,f_{n+3} = \cdots$ with same initial conditions, thus they are equal for all $\,n\,$ by a trivial induction (i.e.  *uniqueness* theorem for recurrences).

To obtain the associated recurrence  sum the following for $\,a\,$ over all $\,3\,$ roots.

$$ a^{n+3}-3a^{n+2} +a^n =\, a^n(a^3-3a^2+1) = 0,\ \ {\rm  for\ any\ root}\ \ a$$

yielding $\ \  \alpha^{n+3} +\beta^{n+3} + \gamma^{n+3} - 3 (\alpha^{n+2} +\beta^{n+2} + \gamma^{n+2}) + (\alpha^{n} +\beta^{n} + \gamma^{n}) \ =\  0$

therefore  $\,\ f_{n+3} - 3f_{n+2} + f_n = 0,\ $ for $\ f_n = \alpha^{n} +\beta^{n} + \gamma^{n}$

TIP $ $ note that $\,4,5, -6\,$ are the roots of the polynomial mod $17.$

Comment: This is the simple way to complete the induction. The OP still needs to verify the congruence for $n=0,1,2$, but Will Jagy seems to have started from that end. +1 to all.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen hi there. Right, I think this OP is generally asking for the quickest trick that will let him answer in a contest, meanwhile learning very little; note how he briefly follows my string of questions but then repeats his standard demand for me to finish by spoonfeeding, "How does this relate to my recurrence?"

Comment: @Jyrki, now that I look at it starting from "To obtain" Bill's answer is lovely.

Comment: Yeah @Will the OP also asked a now deleted version, where it would have made sense to look at the splitting field $\Bbb{Q}(\sin(\pi/9))$ (where the roots are algebraic integers) and ideals therein. But that would be overkill, and won't lead to a clean argument as, due to those distinct modular solutions, the prime $17$ splits.

Comment: Right @Jyrki, they do delete things. Note that he put one comment from his Puzzled417 identity above http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875266/prove-that-alphan-betan-gamman-equiv-4n5n-6n-pmod17#comment3843850_1875266

Comment: I do recall something earlier that involved $\sin 20^\circ$ and the like.

Comment: @Will I got it wrong, it was $\cos(\pi/9)$. Anyway, I will investigate your other remarks. The flag will be pending for some time still, as I will be away (unless another moderator already investigated it). Meanwhile, the problem with splitting primes does not occur in the $17$-adics so I took the liberty of adding a different answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think something basic should be emphasized here. Take $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ as complex numbers (this particular time they are all real, does not matter).
What are the three numbers

$$ \alpha + \beta + \gamma, $$
$$ \beta \gamma + \gamma \alpha + \alpha \beta,  $$
$$ \alpha \beta \gamma?  $$

Comment: Using Vieta's, we see that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma = 3$.

Comment: @user19405892 and the other two?

Comment: The other two are $\beta \gamma+\gamma \alpha+\alpha \beta = 0$ and $\alpha \beta \gamma = -1$.

Comment: That's just $(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^2 = 9-2 \cdot 0 = 9$.

Comment: @user19405892 what about the sum of the cubes? Quickest if you know how to factor $t^3 + u^3 + v^3 - 3 tuv$

Comment: How does this relate to my recurrence?

Comment: @user19405892 aright. the theorem on symmetric polynomials says that anything you want can be found using those three values.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial#Elementary_symmetric_polynomials  In particular, you do not really need to interpret the three roots in $Z/ 17Z,$ you can just work with your $3,9,7.$ To stretch yourself a little, what is $\alpha^4 + \beta^4 + \gamma^4,$ and do the facts so far support the claim about $4,5,-6 \pmod{17}?$

Answer (score 2):

A higher (but not very high) tech solution would be to work inside the ring of $17$-adic integers $\Bbb{Z}_{17}$ (**not to be confused with the residue class ring** $\Bbb{Z}/17\Bbb{Z}$). Hensel's lemma tells us that the zeros $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ of this polynomial are integers in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_{17}$ . Furthermore $\alpha\equiv4\pmod{17\Bbb{Z}_{17}}$ and similarly $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are congruent to the respective modular roots.

The claim then follows from the usual rules of congruences, if we can show that the power sums of the roots are the "same" irrespective of whether we view them as complex numbers or $17$-adic numbers. But actually the power sums $\alpha^n+\beta^n+\gamma^n$ are rational integers. This is immediate from Galois theory. Therefore we are done.

Comment: I see, you answered here. Enjoy Rio de Janeiro. Or Tenerife. Either one.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's identities for a cubic polynomial suggests that in this scenario $P_n = \alpha^n + \beta^n + \gamma^n = 3P_{n-1} - P_{n-3}$, and $P_0 = 3, P_1 = 3, P_2 = 9$.

For the other root sum it suggests polynomial $(x-4)(x-5)(x+6) = x^3-3 x^2-34 x+120$ which has recurrence $P_n = 4^n + 5^n + (-6)^n = 3P_{n-1} - 34P_{i-2} - 120P_{n-3}$, and $P_0 = 3, P_1 = 3, P_2 = 77$.

Taken mod $17$ you get $3P_{n-1} - P_{n-3}$ with $P_0 = 3, P_1 = 3, P_2 = 9$, the same recurrence as before.