# If $x+y+z \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$, where $x,y,z$ are irrationals, then is it true that $x^n + y^n +z^n \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$ for odd $n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Original problem:**

> If $\alpha$ be the greatest positive root of $x^3-3x^2+1=0$, then show that $[\alpha^{1996}]$ is divisible by 17. ($[x]$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$)

**My work:**

It is easily found that if the roots are $\gamma < \beta <\alpha$, then $-1 < \gamma < 0 < \beta < 1$ and $2 < \alpha < 3$, and that they must be irrational. We also have,

$\begin{align*}
\alpha + \beta + \gamma &= 3 \\
\alpha\beta + \beta\gamma + \gamma\alpha &= 0 \\
\alpha\beta\gamma &= -1 \\
\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 &= 9 \\
\alpha^4 + \beta^4 + \gamma^4 &= 81-12 = 69 \equiv 1 \pmod{17}\\
\end{align*}$

Now, we also note that $-\beta < \gamma < 0 < \beta < 0.9$, and using the inequality $(1+x)^r \leq e^{rx}$, we have that $0 < \beta^{1996} + \gamma^{1996} < 0.5$. From Newton's identities, we know that $\alpha^{1996} + \beta^{1996} + \gamma^{1996} \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence, from the definition of the greatest integer function,

$$[\alpha^{1996}] = \alpha^{1996} + \beta^{1996} + \gamma^{1996} = \left(\alpha^4\right)^{499} + \left(\beta^4\right)^{499} + \left(\gamma^4\right)^{499}$$

But we have that $\alpha^4 + \beta^4 + \gamma^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{17} \implies (\alpha^4 + \beta^4 + \gamma^4)^{499} \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$.

To prove the required result, we must show that the rest of the terms of the expansion must sum to a multiple of 17. Although we know that the sum must be an integer, as the terms themselves are irrational, I can't think of any way to show this, or even if it is true or not. Any help or hint regarding this will be appreciated. I am also grateful to any hints on how to solve the original problem in any other easier way.

Comment: Essentially https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875266/prove-that-alphan-betan-gamman-equiv-4n5n-6n-pmod17?rq=1

Comment: @Macavity Thanks a lot for linking that post. For some reason, it was never suggested to me when I was typing my question.